# Show all tasks assigned to me in a tree that extends to the root

Tags: tfs

We have some stories that look like this:

```
User Story - Assigned to someone else
    User Story - Assigned to someone else
        Task - Assigned to ME
        Task - Assigned to someone else
    Task - Assigned to ME
        Task - Assigned to someone else
        Task - Assigned to ME
```

I want to see all tasks that are assigned to me, but I want to see them in a tree that extends to the root so I can see where the task came from.

Like this:

```
User Story - Assigned to someone else
    User Story - Assigned to someone else
        Task - Assigned to ME
    Task - Assigned to ME
        Task - Assigned to ME
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I attached a version of the query you need to create. The bottom part is a group of nobody assigned and @me.  You can change that part if you need to.
[image]

Comment: This gives me all the root level user stories regardless of if I have a task assigned somewhere under it

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment but can't yet. So what you can do is change the filtered linked work item to get the assigned to that you care about. Right now it's filtering on assigned to being empty or assigned to me and being a task or a user story. So you can change that filter to match your need.
The fil